# client Socket won't connect to Server Socket. Cross-origin connection Blocked

Tags: html, express, http, socket.io, cors

I have a server and a html file. The html file calls the io function from socket.io local file I have in the node_modules. I am opening the html file as a local file, and for the server I execute it with `node index.js`

Here is my code:

index.js

```
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
app.use(cors())
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("New ws connection");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Connect Chord</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      const socket = io();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I attacked a screenshot of the error message on the client side console.[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StbZs.png)

Would like to have it resolved so that I do not see any errors on the client, and the server should print "New ws connection".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Comment: yes it does. Thank you Phil.